# Count node by taxonomy term

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, views

I want to build a statistical of ours projects inside my structure.
I have a taxonomy term status with the terms ongoing, achieved, not rated and pending.

An my content type have a relationship to this term.
Now I want to show something like this using view and aggregation.

- ongoing (2)
- achieved (2)
- Not rated (12)
- **pending (0)**

But the issue is the last term **"pending"** is not visible because it have **0** attached node.

But I want to show it with the **0**.
Please how can I solved this issue.

This is my interface of view. The term with **0** node disappear. [image]

In attached my exporting view.
    
`$view = new view();
$view->name = 'clone_view_for_issue';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'CLONE VIEW FOR ISSUE';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially /

/ Display: Master /
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'VIEW DE TEST TAXO';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/ Field: Taxonomy term: Name /
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/ Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name /
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'thematique' => 'thematique',
);

/ Display: Block test 1 /
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block test 1', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Nombre total d\'engagement';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_ajax'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['group_by'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['query'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['relationships'] = FALSE;
/ Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content using Note engagement /
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_note_engagement_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_note_engagement_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_note_engagement_node']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_note_engagement_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_note_engagement_node';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/ Field: Content: Nid /
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_note_engagement_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['empty'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/ Field: Taxonomy term: Name /
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['text'] = ' [name] ([nid])
';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['empty'] = '[view] [name] (0)
';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/ Contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID /
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['id'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_index';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['field'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_note_engagement_node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['default_action'] = 'empty';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['break_phrase'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/ Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name /
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'min' => '',
  'max' => '',
  'value' => '',
  'status' => 'status',
);
/ Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_note_engagement_node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'engagement' => 'engagement',
);`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using a "Content" in views, since the taxonomy term is being removed when there are no nodes referenced. I suggest to use the "Taxonomy Terms" instead of the "Content" to display all the terms and just use a relationship to get the nodes attached.

Please see below:

- Create a taxonomy term type views.
- Filter the view to "Status". (Which is your current vocabulary)

[image]

- Add to relationship your taxonomy field "Content using Status".

[image]

- Turn on aggregation
- Add "NID" field to count nodes associated with the term.

[image]

- Save

Comment: I did exactly your soltion but the status with **0** node disappear. See my interface's capture

Comment: Could you please export your view and attach it here, so I could check it.

Comment: I edited the post and you can see the code of the view

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method available for the same :

```
$tid = 'Enter tid number say 5';
$nids = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid, FALSE);
// count node here
$count = count($nids);
// you can load node content here
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```